# Euler totient function and groups.

Tags: finite-groups, totient-function

Say $\phi(n)=k$ is the number of integers less than n relatively prime to n. Then prove that any integer a relatively prime to n $a^{\phi(n)}=1 \quad mod\quad n$.

My proof

U(n) be the group of integers coprime to n less than n. Then a belongs to this group and order of group is k. Hence $a^k=1$.

This proof is correct right.

Answer (score 1):

If a  (finite) group has order $k$ then of course every element $x$ of the group satisfies $x^k=1$; this is pure group theory.

However to apply this theorem one has to first **show that U(n) is a group in the first place**.
SO one has to do some number-theoretic proof, there is no way to avoid it.